# Detecting a DC current

Tags: current-measurement, shunt

I want to detect if the electronic locker in my differential is functioning. The differential locker is essentially a solenoid that engages the axle locker, however since the wire runs under the vehicle it is exposed, and a damaged wire would go undetected. I have no way of mechanically detecting it (limit switch, plunger, etc), so I need to do it electrically.

The locker's solenoid operates on 12V and draws between 5-8 amps, so assuming the higher value, the locker has an effective resistance of between 1.5 and 2.4 ohms.

I have found some 10A shunt resistors with a voltage drop of 75mV (I'm guessing that means 7.5mohm), which will have minimal impact on the operation of the solenoid. My calculation is that my actual voltage drop will be between 37.5mV and 60mV.

I'm not trying to measure the current, just detect it by lighting an LED (most likely a lighted switch which expects 12V. Most of the articles or information I've found reference OpAmps to measure current, but I just want to detect it, so presumably I would use a PNP transistor, but which one?

I have done some searching, but I don't even know if I'm searching for the right thing.

Comment: Are you wanting some kind of light bulb that lights up somewhere if the wire is damaged and the solenoid is no longer able to be activated? What are your goals here? What does "detecting it" mean, exactly? How do you get notified? Also, there are common ways that faults in the headlights are identified and reported in vehicles. Have you read about how these are achieved?

Comment: Sorry, I edited out the part where I wanted to light an LED. The goal is to light an LED when current is flowing (ie: the locker is activated) such that if the light doesn't come on, we know there's a severed connection somewhere. Edited the post. I haven't looked into headlight fault detection. Will research.

Comment: So, is it correct to say that the light should always come on when there is 5-8 amps flowing in the solenoid and that the light should otherwise be off?

Comment: Correct. However, my goal isn't to do over-current detection.

Comment: If you had a "black box" device, would you cut it into the solenoid circuit at the positive voltage terminal? Or would you cut it into the solenoid circuit at the negative voltage terminal? (Basically, you need to insert an "ammeter" into the circuit. But the ammeter itself needs access to power, too, so I'm wondering which end is "up" here, so to speak. High side insertion or low side insertion?) I think I do get the idea that you are considering inserting the "shunt" resistor in series to develop a voltage.

Comment: I was thinking high side insertion, as the low side is the vehicle chassis and my intent was to insert the shunt into the circuit near the switch in the cabin. It would still detect a broken wire of failed solenoid. If there's a better way than inserting a shunt, then  I'm all for it, but that seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @Jonk it's automotive so low side will be difficult to say the least.

Comment: @Trevor I was trying not to assume anything here. (I've had cars with positive ground and this site covers the world.) But true enough.

Comment: @jonk true enuf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to toss in another thought:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f178VD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

None of the transistors need to be power BJTs; they can all be small TO-92 types (or smaller.) Optimally, it would be nice if they were matched. But I added \$R_4\$ as a potentiometer so you can make adjustments, instead. This also covers variations in your \$R_1\$ value. Nominally, it should be about 20-30% of the indicated value. But your mileage may vary depending on the matching of \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ and your actual \$R_1\$ value. (I thought about suggesting a BCM62 for matching but then there is \$R_1\$, so I think the potentiometer is useful until you know what you actually need here.) \$Q_3\$ is totally non-critical. I'm assuming there is a high-side switch here, so \$SW_1\$ is there to represent that detail. (Probably fused, too, but I didn't add that.) If you get BJTs that can stand off some decent voltage (like 2N5401), then there's probably no real need for load-dump protection.

I've not gone through this for all the practical details of an automotive situation. It's more a behavioral approach that avoids opamps. It might work okay, as is.

---

Just for grins, I tossed the above circuit into LTSpice and used the standard BJTs and \$R_4=22\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ on a lark. The DC sweep came out this way:

[image]

You can play with either \$R_2\$ or \$R_4\$ to change the location where the switching takes place.

If \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ are matched, it won't even budge even if you vary \$\beta\$ and \$V_{BE}\$ over a reasonable range. Of course.. that's if they are matched. Of course it will work fine then. So if you can, pick \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$ as matched pairs such as BCV62 or BCM62. They won't stand off a load dump well. But they might survive it.

Unmatched, and messing with \$\beta\$ and \$V_{BE}\$ (as a function of \$I_{SAT}\$), I get the following spread:

[image]

That's with a fair amount of variation on the BJTs. So it's not horrible, so long as you get the same part number. But it may require some tweaking of either \$R_2\$ and/or \$R_4\$ to make it work well for you.

---

I've added \$R_5\$ to prevent a mistake in setting the \$R_4\$ potentiometer to an accidentally harmful value. The value of \$R_5\$ should be the same as the value chosen for \$R_2\$, roughly speaking. I had imagined using a potentiometer until the right value was measured, then replacing it with an actual resistor. But if the potentiometer is kept, then the value of \$R_5\$  could be a little less than \$R_2\$ (as little as half) but probably shouldn't be more than 25% larger. Somewhere in that range should be okay if the same exact value isn't available.

I've added some possible protection schemes to the circuit. The diode-only would need to be something with perhaps \$200\:\textrm{V}\$ reverse voltage  and at least \$10\:\textrm{A}\$ capability. The downside of it is that the flyback current dies out slowly. And in this case, it might die out way too slowly. The diode+zener combination provides a high voltage so the flyback current pulse can die out more quickly. But both parts must be capable of the same high current potentials and I'd want about \$30\:\textrm{V}\$ across the pair -- so select a zener in that area, if possible. Finally, there are also  automotive MOVs (Littlefuse makes them, for example) which can repeatedly absorb solenoid flyback energy as well. They come in a variety of voltage ratings. Again, I'd be looking for about \$30\:\textrm{V}\$ here.

Comment: +1 nice.. my turn to be picky though ;).... Winding R4 to the wrong end = smoke...

Comment: I'd be using a dual matched pair like a 
DMMT3906W or a SSM2220PZ

Comment: @Trevor I've got reams of BCV61, BCV62, BCM61, and BCM62. Those are not just on the same substrates, but the BCM variety are matched on both beta and \$V_{BE}\$ as well. But their \$V_{CEO}\$ is too low for feeling secure about load dumps. Haven't yet looked at those two pairings you mentioned, but I can guess what they look like just from the number. Will check and see how good the matching is.

Comment: @Trevor Okay. I looked at the DMMT3906W. Nice. Price is good, too. (I picked up my pairs for less than 10 cents per pair, but that was a while ago.) Probably, I should get some of those and have some fun.

Comment: Thanks guys. Much appreciated. I will have to order some parts and play around with it, maybe put  10k in series with R4 if I use a lot to protect it.

Comment: One thing you DO need on there is a 2A+fly-back diode. Ground up to rail. You have to assume the car manufacturer did not add one at the switch, so when it goes off the top of your (and mine) circuit will spike up large. Might as well make it a 15V Zener while you are at it to kill 2 stones with one bird.

Comment: Make that 10A..

Comment: That's a good call on the Zener diode. I think I will prototype this with some 2N3906. Easier than working with SOT for me.

Comment: @Prdufresne It would also be pretty simple to flip the output of either of these circuits to light up a BRD (Big Red Diode) when the power is on but the current does not flow... that is... a warning light instead of an active light.

Comment: @Trevor Well, this whole thing was just tossed out as a random thought and more behavioral than real. Now we've got the suggestions for adding some fixed resistance to the pot and inductor flyback. I guess it's starting to get real. I will plug in a few things into the schematic (though I would not have minded you editing it.)

Comment: @Prdufresne Added some solenoid flyback protection thoughts. Just so you know. The diode by itself is probably my last choice because it might take seconds to do its job. The diode+zener or an automotive MOV of sufficient size might be the best choice here. Something that will yield about 30 V across the coil during flyback would be good.

Comment: :) Yes Jonk.. see what you started. But then again.. this is what makes trolling this forum fun.

Comment: @Trevor I'd wanted to toss out a thought that would be junk box parts and accommodate discrete BJT variations using a pot. Then someone (who shall remain nameless) mentioned matched BJT pairs. Which is of course better, though boutique and less likely as junk box parts, and might mean that a design without a pot could be achieved. So I had to go Spice the darned thing to add more. Then someone (still nameless) mentioned the need for flyback protection -- good point by the way. Still more. So... maybe I toss these out as a minor comment to your answer next time... ;)

Comment: Just a quick sanity check. While searching for R1, I've found them with ratings from 15W to 100W. The locker itself will draw 8A @ 12V, so 96W, however R1 will only have a voltage drop of about 60mV. Since it's in series with the load, however, I assume I need to size it for 100W. Am I correct here?

Comment: @Prdufresne The power required (its dissipation) is just the current times the voltage. So if the current is 8 A and the voltage drop across it is 60 mV, then this is half a watt, or so. All of your ratings are WAY OVER this. So I think you'd be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is automotive I have to assume the wire is on the +12V side. As such you need to use high side current sensing. There are numerous devices that do this like the [LTC6101](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6101fh.pdf).

[image]

Whichever sense method you chose, you would then need to feed the analog value into an appropriate comparator circuit and have it turn on an LED when current is detected.

Like this perhaps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEF5Jb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Choose values for R2 and R3 to set the threshold voltage to turn on the light when the current is say over 1A.

NOTE: Since this circuit takes it's power from the solenoids power line it consumes zero power when that is turned off.

**ADDITION:**

You have to assume the car manufacturer did not add a fly-back diode at the switch or the solenoid, so when it goes off the top of the circuit will spike up large. As such I added a 10A fly-back diode. Note I chose a ZENER to also protect against large positive voltage spikes from the car's environment. The Zener part does not need to be 10A though so two diodes, high current rectifier and low current Zener, may be cheaper.

Comment: I'm mostly worried about directly exposing opamps to a vehicle's power system. May want to add a zener (or something) for some kind of load dump protection (excess of 100 V and gnarly when it happens.)

Comment: @jonk yes perhaps a zener limiter would be prudent. I don't think the diode will care about the noise much. Decouplers are probably even overkill with this LOL.

Comment: I tried simulating the circuit you shared above with a Load to the left of Rsense and a 12V battery to the right, but I couldn't generate a voltage differential across the LED. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong in selecting my R2 and R3 values. I set Rsense to 7.5mohms and my load to 2.4ohms.

Comment: @Prdufresne unless you have the simulation model for the LTC part you wont be able to. It is just drawn as an op-amp because they did, and it has the right connections.. it is more complicated than that internally